# BeautifulSoup won't remove i element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am learning how to parse and manipulate `html` using `beautiful soup` like so:

```
from lxml.html import parse
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = 'some-url-here'
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"}) 
parsed = urllib2.urlopen( req )
soup = BeautifulSoup(parsed)

for elem in soup.findAll(['script', 'style', 'i']):
    elem.extract()

for main_body in soup.findAll("div", {"role" : "main"}):
    print main_body.getText(separator=u' ')
```

The result contains `<i>` tags and I can't figure out how to remove them. How can this be accomplished and why is the only tag not to be removed by the above code?

Comment: Can you share the html? The code should work fine as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is actually the fact you are using the deprecated *Beautifulsoup3*, install  [*bs4*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)  and everything will work fine:

```
In [10]: import urllib2
In [11]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # bs4

In [12]: url = 'https://www.gwr.com/'

In [13]: req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': "Magic Browser"})

In [14]: parsed = urllib2.urlopen(req)

In [15]: soup = BeautifulSoup(parsed,"html.parser")

In [16]: tags = soup.find_all(['script','style','i'])

In [17]: print(len(tags))
25

In [18]: for elem in tags:
   ....:         elem.extract()
   ....:     

In [19]: assert len(soup.find_all(['script','style','i'])) == 0

In [20]:
```

Comment: No prob, you're welcome. As an aside, if you know how to xpaths/css then lxml would be more efficient than using bs4.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out. Have just dived in to Python over the last month so suspect I've a lot of modules to uncover that will become part of the 'staple diet'.